# Cannot find Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Sharing.SecurableObjectExtensions.GetSharingInformation() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sharepoint

I am trying to call the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Sharing.SecurableObjectExtensions.GetSharingInformation() method which is present in Microsoft's documentation in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-csomspt/3b13bf76-d6ca-4918-b500-7585fecdf79b.

I installed some sharepoint nuget packages but the class *SecurableObjectExtensions* is not found in the namespace *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Sharing*. Can someone could help me with this problem?

This is my actual code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Sharing;

namespace Borrar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>")
            {
                Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@domain", securePassword),
            };

            context.Load(context.Web, w => w.Title);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            List docList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            context.Load(docList);

            // This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll"
            // so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in.
            CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
            ListItemCollection items = docList.GetItems(query);

            // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query).
            context.Load(items);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
            {
                //The problem is here
                var sharingInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Sharing.SecurableObjectExtensions.GetSharingInformation(listItem);
                Console.WriteLine(sharingInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be REST api

https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2018/04/04/externally-sharing-getsharinginformation-rest-api/

As mentioned "The protocol server endpoint is formed by appending "_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery" to the URL of the site (2), "

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-csomspt/1eb5bf91-ac5b-4fed-b75f-9d9d19a501e8

Comment: But i using an sdk for accesing the api from c#. Sorry for my english.